# Can topological degrees of freedoms interact?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, mass, quantum-gravity, topological-field-theory, chern-simons-theory

**Question**

Can topological degrees of freedom interact with:

1. other topological dof's
2. other local dof's

**Premise**

For concreteness, I can't understand why the following term will not be allowed in a Lagrangian.

$$\mathcal{L} \propto \mu_{ph}\  \epsilon_{abc}\ A_d \partial^b A^c\  \delta g^{cd} $$

where, $A^\mu$ is a topologically massive photon with mass $\mu_{ph}$ and $\delta g^{cd}$ is a perturbation to the topologically massive graviton.

I understand that a Chern-Simons mass term is independent of the metric, but this does not make it obvious why perturbations of the metric will also be spared from taking part in interactions.

**EDIT** (an hour later)

I hoped - invariance under coordinate transformations could perhaps rule out the proposed term from the Lagrangian. Instead, allowed terms are:

$$ \mathcal{L} \propto \mu_{ph}\  \epsilon^{abd}\ A_a \partial^b A^c\  \delta g{^c_d} $$

*The plot thickens...*